# Make app server sided

Tags: android, sql-server, webserver

I am trying to make an app that will allow users to manage their activities and so. And for this, I need to store all the data on some server. What should I use ? Can you recommend me some kind of good webhosting with huge or possibky unlimited database space ? Thank you very much for your suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `www.parse.com or`www.baasbox.com  for backing up your data. Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Its not really possible to provide better than the typical "it depends" answer - there are a whole bunch of trade-offs to consider when selecting which data store to use (let alone how you choose to host it)

However, given you've explicitly tagged sql-server I'd suggest taking a look at Microsoft's [Azure](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/) platform (and perhaps specifically their hosted [SQL Database](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/sql-database-get-started/)) as it should satisfy all the points in your question.